# GWT: External obfuscated CSS

Tags: gwt, obfuscation

GWT automatically obfuscates CSS name during compilation.  I'm looking for way to externalize this CSS that was obfuscated by GWT after compilation, rather then inline it inside HTML.

Any suggestion? I still want to use the built-in compilation to obfuscate CSS, but I want to redirect the output to an external .css file. Is this possible? Does it needs a custom compiler linker? Any example on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable inlining of resources (all `ClientBundle` resources though) by adding the following to your gwt.xml:

```
<set-property name="ClientBundle.enableInlining" value="false" />
```

Comment: may i know how to feed the obfuscated css and put into external .css file ?